# Definition of universe of field of fractions (lost in translation)

Tags: field-theory, translation-request

I need to find a definition of the *universe* (ger. *Grundmenge*) of the *field of fractions* $Quot(R)$ (ger. *Quotientenkörper*) of integral domain $R$. The full version is "*die Grundmenge des Quotientenkörpers*", maybe it's indivisible in translation. The only thing that comes to my mind so far is $$M=\{a:a\in R \vee a^{-1}\in R\}$$

Comment: You might want to look at the construction part of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions.

Comment: @Shervin Sorouri Yes I've looked there already, it made me think that universe is set of all fractions without division in equivalence classes which would make it the field of fratctions

Comment: In model theoretic terms atleast, when you have a structure $\mathfrak{A} = \langle A, R_1, \dots , R_n, \dots , f_1 , \dots , f_n, \dots , c_1, \dots, c_k , \dots \rangle$, where $A$ is a set, the $R_i$'s are relations on $A$ and etc, $A$ is called the universe of $\mathfrak{A}$. Now in your case letting $Quot(R) = \langle Q, +, \times, 0, 1\rangle$, the universe of $Quot(R)$ would be $Q$ which is the equivalence classes you construct. I hope this can be helpful.